# adding two NSMutableArrays to an array and filtering data with ascending in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, arrays

I am doing location part and getting distance in for loop by adding distance in to NSMutableArray like this
this numbers are stored as NSNumber
3.2,
1.2,
5,
,
,

like this and in one case am getting data from core data in an array like this as an names ...
This names are stores as NSString
D,
B,
A,
C
,
,

like this so here
3.2 belongs to D,
1.2 belongs to B,
,
,

like this so i want to filter this data with distance 
like
1.2,
3.2,
5,
,
,
like this but am not able to do need some help

This is the Code am getting data from core data

```
NSFetchRequest * dealFetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Deal"];
NSArray * array = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:dealFetch error:&error];
NSArray * nameAa = [array valueForKey:@"nameAttribute"];
NSLog(@"%@",nameAa);
```

This is the code am gettin
g Locations

```
locaFilterArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int l = 0 ; l < dealArray.count; l++) {
    Deal * deal = (Deal *)dealArray[l];
    NSArray * locArray = [[deal locationRelation]allObjects];
    double minValue = 10000;
    if (locArray.count > 0) {
        for (int l = 0; l < locArray.count ; l++) {
            DealLocation * location = (DealLocation *)locArray[l];
            double latitude = [[location latitude]doubleValue];
            double longitude = [[location longitude]doubleValue];
            CLLocation * cdLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude];
            CLLocation * currLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:appDelegate.currentLatitude longitude:appDelegate.currentLongitude];
            CLLocationDistance distance = [currLocation distanceFromLocation:cdLocation]/1000;
               if (distance < minValue) {
                   minValue = distance;
               }
           }
    } else {
           minValue = 5;
    }
    float va = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f",minValue]floatValue];
    NSNumber *numb = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:va];
    [locaFilterArray addObject:numb];
}
NSLog(@"%@",locaFitlerArray);
```

**Wow i got the solution see the below code how it is working**

```
NSFetchRequest * dealFetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Deal"];
            NSArray * array = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:dealFetch error:&error];
            NSArray * nameAa = [array valueForKey:@"nameAttribute"];
            NSArray * locArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:locaFilterArray, nil];
            NSDictionary * dd = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:locaFilterArray forKeys:nameAa];
            NSLog(@"%@",[self sortKeysByIntValue:dd]);

- (NSArray *)sortKeysByIntValue:(NSDictionary *)dictionary {

    NSArray *sortedKeys = [dictionary keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        int v1 = [obj1 intValue];
        int v2 = [obj2 intValue];
        if (v1 < v2)
            return NSOrderedAscending;
        else if (v1 > v2)
            return NSOrderedDescending;
        else
            return NSOrderedSame;
    }];
    return sortedKeys;
}
```

Comment: Filter or sort an array based on distance with relevance of Value (D,B, ..)??

Comment: i am storint 3.2 , 1.2 , 5 ,,, as nsnumbers

Comment: Post your code which you have tried ..

Comment: Create one dictionary with names as key and numbers as value then you can easily sort it.

Comment: can you give me code

Comment: This is nice: `float va = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f",minValue]floatValue];`.

Comment: I was being sarcastic.

Comment: am not good at english what is sarcastic..

Comment: Well what I mean is "this is not good".  Look at the code; you are converting a float to a string and then back to a float.  Remove that line and the following line and do `NSNumber *numb = @(minValue);` instead or better still `[locaFilterArray addObject:@(minValue)];`.

Comment: dear trojan if i print the values with your code i am getting like this 25.2445555, 1.00000445  .... like this stupid values so am limiting the values to 25.2 , 1.0 .... you got my point what am doing

Comment: @Thanks You are doing it wrong.  That is a *presentation* issue, not a *storage* issue.

Comment: Okay I understood you want me to store as you said and presentation as .1f right

Comment: is that correct @trojan

Comment: Yes.  The precision is a display issue.  Just store the value as you get it.

Comment: Yaa i got you i will do that thank you